# How to detect sprite objects touching each other in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making a game/program stop after the person reaches the end and touches an object that i would like to end the program. So how do I detect sprite object touching each other. The problem is from code.org a website for beginners :) .

```
var sophia = createSprite(370,30,10,10);

var block1 = createSprite(318, 30, 10, 150);
var block2 = createSprite(375, 60, 70, 10);
var block3 = createSprite(321, 200, 10, 150);
var block4 = createSprite(376, 125, 74, 20);
var block5 = createSprite(280, 115, 30, 60);
var block6 = createSprite(244, 60, 110, 10);
var block7 = createSprite(194, 20, 10, 70);
var block8 = createSprite(220, 12, 3, 3);
//what this
var block9 = createSprite(276, 160, 80, 10);
var block10 = createSprite(220, 90, 90, 10);
var block11= createSprite(169, 235, 10, 330);
var block12= createSprite(120, 65, 50, 50);
var block13= createSprite(174, 20, 30, 30);
var block14= createSprite(310, 248, 0.5, 0.5);
//insta win
var block15= createSprite(240, 280, 130, 10);
var block16= createSprite(245, 212, 30, 30);
var block17= createSprite(205, 240, 30, 30);
var block18= createSprite(205, 170, 30, 30);
var block19= createSprite(286, 190, 30, 30);
var block20= createSprite(286, 240, 30, 47);
var block21= createSprite(45, 60, 60, 60);
var block22= createSprite(84, 300, 135, 390);

var secret1 = createSprite(85, 13, 20, 20);
//white teleport
var secret2 = createSprite(188, 108, 20, 20);
//white teleport
var secret3 = createSprite(158, 205, 0.5, 0.5);
//teleport good
var block23 = createSprite(6, 213, 0.5, 0.5);
//bad teleport
var block24 = createSprite(264, 320, 10, 70);
var block25 = createSprite(264, 390, 10, 35);
var block26 = createSprite(264, 361, 0.5, 0.5);
//mastermind
var trophy = createSprite(385, 385, 30, 30);
//Winning message
var block27 = createSprite(320, 360, 10, 100);
var block28 = createSprite(360, 305, 90, 10);

function draw() {
  background("white");
  createEdgeSprites();
  sophia.bounceOff(edges);
  
  if(keyDown(UP_ARROW)) {
    sophia.velocityX = 0;
    sophia.velocityY = -4;
  }
  
  if(keyDown(DOWN_ARROW)){
    sophia.velocityX= 0;
    sophia.velocityY= 4;
  }
  
  if(keyDown(LEFT_ARROW)){
    sophia.velocityX= -4;
    sophia.velocityY= 0;
  }
  
  if(keyDown(RIGHT_ARROW)){
    sophia.velocityX= 4;
    sophia.velocityY= 0;
  }
    if(keyWentUp(RIGHT_ARROW)||keyWentUp(UP_ARROW)||keyWentUp(DOWN_ARROW)||keyWentUp(LEFT_ARROW)){
    sophia.velocityX=0;
    sophia.velocityY=0;
  }
  if(sophia.isTouching(block1)||sophia.isTouching(block2)||sophia.isTouching(block3)||sophia.isTouching(block4)||sophia.isTouching(block5)||sophia.isTouching(block6)||sophia.isTouching(block7)||sophia.isTouching(block9)||sophia.isTouching(block10)||sophia.isTouching(block11)||sophia.isTouching(block12)||sophia.isTouching(block13)||sophia.isTouching(block15)||sophia.isTouching(block16)||sophia.isTouching(block17)||sophia.isTouching(block18)||sophia.isTouching(block19)||sophia.isTouching(block20)||sophia.isTouching(block21)||sophia.isTouching(block22)||sophia.isTouching(block23)||sophia.isTouching(block24)||sophia.isTouching(block25)||sophia.isTouching(block27)||sophia.isTouching(block28)){
    sophia.x=370;
    sophia.y=30;
    sophia.velocityY=0;
    sophia.velocityX=0;
  }
  
  if(sophia.isTouching(block26)){
    textSize(12);
    text("It was a trap", 178, 300);
    sophia.x=370;
    sophia.y=30;
    sophia.velocityY=0;
    sophia.velocityX=0;
  }
  
  if(sophia.isTouching(block8)){
    sophia.x=230;
    sophia.y=315;
    sophia.velocityY=0;
    sophia.velocityX=0;
  }
    if(sophia.isTouching(secret1)||sophia.isTouching(secret2)||sophia.isTouching(block14)||sophia.isTouching(secret3)){
    sophia.x=350;
    sophia.y=365;
    sophia.velocityY=0;
    sophia.velocityX=0;
  }
  
  if(sophia.isTouching(trophy)){
    textSize(20);
    text("You won GG.", 140, 180);
    endGame;
  }
  
  sophia.shapeColor="blue";
  block1.shapeColor="black";
  block2.shapeColor="black";
  block3.shapeColor="black";
  block4.shapeColor="black";
  block5.shapeColor="black";
  block6.shapeColor="black";
  block7.shapeColor="black";
  block8.shapeColor="Purple";
  block9.shapeColor="black";
  block10.shapeColor="black";
  block11.shapeColor="black";
  block12.shapeColor="black";
  block13.shapeColor="black";
  block14.shapeColor="black";
  block15.shapeColor="black";
  block16.shapeColor="black";
  block17.shapeColor="black";
  block18.shapeColor="black";
  block19.shapeColor="black";
  block20.shapeColor="black";
  block21.shapeColor="black";
  block22.shapeColor="black";
  block23.shapeColor="black";
  block24.shapeColor="black";
  block25.shapeColor="black";
  block26.shapeColor="black";
  block27.shapeColor="black";
  block28.shapeColor="black";
  secret1.shapeColor="white";
  secret2.shapeColor="white";
  secret3.shapeColor="white";
  trophy.shapeColor="Yellow";
  
  text("<--What this?", 240, 15);
  //troll teleport
  
  textSize(10);
  text("Choose one side if you came here.", 8, 100);
  // good and bad
  
  textSize(12);
  text("Trophy!!", 345, 350);
  
  text("Sophia (You)", 330, 10);
  
  text("Find", 340, 150);
  text("hidden", 340, 161);
  text("teleporters", 340, 172);
  text("to", 340, 183);
  text("get", 340, 194);
  text("to", 340, 205);
  text("the", 340, 216);
  text("trophy", 340, 227);
  text("and", 340, 238);
  text("win", 340, 249);
  text("!!!", 340, 260);
  
  drawSprites();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean touches another object. Did you meant matches with other element or number ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: Umm i meant like if(object.isTouching(object2)){} Then whats the command that i put in the flower brackets to end the program